# How many equivalency classes are there in a statement with 5 letters?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many equivalence classes are there for statements formed with 5 letters; i.e. how many non-logically equivalent statements consist of 5 variable letters?

Really confused about this problem, I guessed it would be 26 choose 1, 5 times giving an answer of 130 but this sounds wrong.

Comment: What's the question?  Can you give an example of two non-logically equivalent statements with $5$ letters?

Comment: There are an
infinite number of statements which can be constructed using the variable p and logical connectives. For example:
p → p, p ∨ p, (p∨ ∼ p) → (p ∧ p), etc. However, it can be shown that all possible statements constructed with just
one variable letter are all logically equivalent to one of four statements; i.e. there are only four equivalence classes
for statements formed by one variable letter.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about how $(A\wedge B)\vee C$ is logically equivalent to $(A\wedge C)\vee (B\wedge C)$ but different than $A\wedge (B\vee C)$.  An equivalence class of equivalent logical statements involving a collection of variables can be uniquely described by it's truth table.  There are $2^5$ rows in the truth table for five variables, each row of which can either take the value of true or false.  Apply multiplication principle (*a.k.a. rule of product*) and conclude.

Comment: @JMoravitz can you please explain this a bit further? I have written out what I believe to be all possibilities. Assuming the 5 different letters are A={a,b,c,d,e}. I believe there would only be 32 possibilities. Is that the final answer or am I missing something?

Comment: @AllenRogers $32$ is the number of subsets of $A=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$.  It is the number of different equivalence classes for a relation on $A$.  Equivalently, it is the number of ways to partition $A$ into exactly two parts.  If you are wanting to know how many equivalence relations there can be for a relation on $A$, you would be wanting an ordered partition number [which in this case would be 52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).  This is however an answer to a completely different question than the question you are being asked.

Comment: Your question as written is asking for *the number of non-logically equivalent statements there are*!  You gave the example of how with just one variable, there are four logical statements that can be made.  With two variables, you have for example $p\vee q, p\wedge q, \neg p\vee q, \neg p\wedge q, p\vee (q\vee \neg q),\dots$.  I say again, consider the truth tables.  Each way of filling out the truth table will give you a different logical statement and two logical statements who have the same truth table are considered "the same" so the question is how many different ways can you fill it out

Comment: @JMoravitz I was misunderstanding the question, that makes it a bit easier. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

For two variables: we have the following truth tables:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}a&b&a\vee b\\0&0&0\\0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&1\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}a&b&a\wedge b\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\\1&1&1\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}a&b&a\implies b\\0&0&1\\0&1&1\\1&0&0\\1&1&1\end{array}$$

etc...

Notice that the truth table for $a\implies b$ is the same as the truth table for $\neg a\vee b$, so these are considered "the same."  As such, we recognize that any way of filling out the final column of the truth table will correspond uniquely to an equivalence class of logical statements.

The question is then, how many different ways can we fill out the final column.

You correctly mentioned in a comment earlier that there are essentially only four different phrases for a single variable, namely $1,p,\neg p, 0$ corresponding to the truth tables:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc|ccc|ccc|c}p&1&&p&p&&p&\neg p&&p&0\\0&1&&0&0&&0&1&&0&0\\1&1&&1&1&&1&0&&1&0\end{array}$$

As mentioned there are only four essentially different phrases, but there are many ways that each phrase can be written.  For example $p$ could be written as $(p\vee p)\wedge p$, or $1$ could be written $p\implies p$, or $0$ could be written as $p\implies \neg p$ or as $p\wedge \neg p$ etc...

To count how many possible truth tables there are, look at how many rows there are in the truth table to fill out.  For one variable there were two rows to fill out.  For two variables there are four rows to fill out.  For three there are eight, and so on.  For five variables there are $32$ rows to fill out.

For each of those rows, the final column will have either a zero or will have a one.  There are two options for each of the $32$ rows' entries.  Apply multiplication principle and conclude.